# Exponential Integrator to solve PDE with Stiff term

Tags: finite-volume, stiffness

I wish to solve an equation like the following,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(A(x)f\right)=S(x,t)f$$
where $A(x,f)f$ and $S(x,t)f$ are the advection and the source terms.
When I naively try to incorporate the source term while discretizing the advection part via an upwind scheme, for example, the solution starts to generate oscillations.
The discretization is described in the following,
$$\frac{f^{n+1}_{i}-f^{n}_{i}}{dt}=-\frac{\mathcal{F}_{i+\frac{1}{2}}^{n}-\mathcal{F}_{i-\frac{1}{2}}^{n}}{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}-x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}+S\left(x_{i},t^{n}\right)f^{n}_{i}$$
with $$\mathcal{F}_{i+\frac{1}{2}}^{n}=\begin{cases}
      A\left(x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}\right)f^{n}_{i} & \text{if $A\left(x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}\right)>0$}\\
      A\left(x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}\right)f^{n}_{i+1} & \text{if $A\left(x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}\right)<0$}
    \end{cases}. $$
The same discretization is giving the right output when $S=0$.
I found out the problem is related to the time dependency of $S$, the source is sometimes getting very large which is causing the problem.
I found out that exponential integrator can be used to mitigate such problems but I am not quite sure how to implement it for the current problem.
The literature that I find starts with the following equation $$\frac{df}{dt}=\mathcal{K}f+\mathcal{G}(t,f)\\
\implies f^{n+1}=e^{\mathcal{K}dt}+\int_{0}^{dt}e^{\mathcal{K}\left(dt-\tau\right)}G\left(t^{n}+\tau,f^{n+\tau}\right)\,d\tau$$
where $\mathcal{K}$ is the term responcible for stiffness and $\mathcal{G}$ is some function.
I understand for the current problem $\mathcal{K}=S(x,t)$ but I do not know how to connect $\mathcal{G}$ with the advection part and how to compute the above integral.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use an exponential integrator or do you just want a way to handle the stiffness? You might be able to just treat the source terms implicitly in order to resolve the stiffness and that's likely to be a lot easier. Do you know if $S$ is always negative? Do you have some upper / lower bounds on the values it can take?

Comment: $S$ can take negative as well as positive. I read that exponential integrator gives to exact relation when $G$ is 0, thats why I was interested in that. So when advection becomes 0 I could get an exact result.

Comment: In your discretised equation, you evaluate the source term at time $t_n$, not $t_{n+1}$. The explicitness is causing the instability. You should try to evaluate it implicitly at the new time point instead. Maybe using a splitter approach may help you cope with the computational / implementation details. Exponential integrators are especially interesting for the linear parts, which the source term is most likely not.

Comment: The time step size for this problem isn't just determined by the CFL condition, but also by the size of $S$. What happens if you make the time step small?

Comment: @Laurent90, for the current case this is difficult to achieve, as the value of $S$ is computed from some other equation through integrating its solution at time $t^n$.

Comment: @Sayan then maybe you can add S as solution components satisfying algebraic equations. Your system is then a differential-algebraic one, which may require some more advanced solution methods, many of which are already available.

Comment: @Laurent90 Can you give some more information on this please.